# Do all stars Turn into Black Holes?

Tags: black-holes, earth, stars

If all stars turn into black Holes one day, in far future, what will happen to Earth if Sun becomes a Black Hole.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/99375/why-does-a-star-beyond-a-certain-mass-limit-chandrasekhar-limit-only-become-a?rq=1

Comment: See also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7732/.

Comment: No. There is a minimum size that this is possible at and Sol is about 20% thereof from memory. If the sun was able to become a black hole and did so the future would look very dark! :-). BUT odds are that before that the sun would have expanded to the point where it engulfed the earth.